# trying to execute a SQL query from within a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to execute a SQL query from within a PHP function but I keep getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /homepages/23/d363590707/htdocs/bNames.php5 on line 14

Line 14 is the line with the prepare method in the following method:

```
function testing()
{
    $query = "SELECT `no` FROM `brandNames` WHERE `id` = $index";
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);   <--- line 14 -----------------<<<
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($no);
    $stmt->fetch(); 
}
```

note:  when I stick the code block in the page(without using a function) the query works and I don't have any problems.

also, I intend to add parameters to this function to replace the table name, column names, and values.  This was just a version that had the least amount of things that could go wrong yet still illustrate my problem.

thanks in advance

Edit: This is what the file looks like:

```
<?php
    require_once('connectvars.php'); //contains the info used in mysqli_connect

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);


    function testing($dbc)
    {
        $query = "SELECT `no` FROM `brandNames` WHERE `id` = $index";
        $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($no);
        $stmt->fetch(); 
    }

//more code
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$dbc` defined? It seems like it's out of scope.

Comment: @GioBorje believe it is in global scope, I edited my OP to show what it looks like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you could define `$dbc` as `global`, I would suggest simply passing `$dbc` into the function:

```
function testing($dbc)
{
    $query = "SELECT `no` FROM `brandNames` WHERE `id` = $index";
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);   <--- line 14 -----------------<<<
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($no);
    $stmt->fetch(); 
}
```

Now, when you call `testing()`, you need to pass in `$dbc`: `testing($dbc);`.

Comment: now I am getting an error on the next line (execute).  Any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: @LoganBesecker `$index` isn't defined, so your query is invalid: `SELECT ... WHERE id =  `.

Comment: oh jeeze, that's a slight oversight haha.  Thank you.  that solved my last problem.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the $dbc object (PDO, probably?) is not in the scope of your function.
You can read more about this here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

To fix this, you could try adding the following line to the top of your function:

```
global $dbc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a `global $dbc;` at the start of your function to bring it [into the function's scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).